# Orbeon Forms - Compile error in IntelliJ IDEA - util.Try

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, orbeon

I am trying to compile Orbeon Forms in IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.1 Community Edition, but I am getting compile errors.

1. Checked out the branch origin/4.7-ce
2. Opened the project with IntelliJ
3. Got on error: Load error: undefined path variables. MESSAGE is undefined. `Fix it`
4. Fixed the MESSAGE error by entering C:\temp as the value. I don't know if this matters.
5. Installed the Scala and File Watchers plugins
6. Configured the Java SDK as jdk1.7.0_09
7. Removed the scala-sdk that was referencing non-existent scala compiler, library, reflect jars in my $USER_HOME\.ivy2\cache directory.
8. Installed the Scala 2.10.3 SDK and configured as a library in the project.
9. Make Project
10. Got 94 errors, all related to the util and xml packages. I would have expected the packages to be scala.util and scala.xml.

Example errors:

```
orbeon-forms\src\main\scala\org\orbeon\oxf\common\PEVersion.scala
Error:(34, 8) object Try is not a member of package util<br/>
              import util.Try
```

```
orbeon-forms\src\main\scala\org\orbeon\oxf\fb\AlertsAndConstraintsOps.scala<br/>
Error:(46, 9) type mismatch;<br/>
              found   : scala.xml.Elem<br/>
              required: org.orbeon.saxon.om.NodeInfo<br/>
                 toXML     currentLang<br/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry haven't had time to look into this one yet. It *should* work, although we use the Ultimate edition of IntelliJ. The first error is definitely not right, as `scala.util.Try` is a built-in Scala class. Could it be that the `scala-library.jar` is not pointed to correctly?

Comment: @ebruchez `scala-library.jar` is included in the scala-sdk-2.10.3 global library. The import in PEVersion.scala is `util.Try` not `scala.util.Try`. See [src](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/oxf/common/PEVersion.scala). Changing it to `scala.util.Try` fixes both the above errors. However, I am left with a few more e.g.,: 
`Error:(80, 58) type mismatch;
 found   : org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.XFormsError.ServerError
 required: <notype>
            containingDocument.addServerError(ServerError(t))`

Comment: @ebruchez I just noticed a message at the top of the source: 
`No IDEA annotations attached to the JDK IDEA IC-139.225.3 (idea path), some issues will not be found`. When I clicked Attach annotations it showed me that there was one more file trying to import `util.Try`. Once I fixed that, the project compiled successfully. I can then run the orbeon-war task successfully from IntelliJ. I'm still confused why this did not compile without the change. I checked out another copy that I didn't import into IntelliJ. It compiled fine with only 'ant orbeon-war`.

Comment: Oddly, though the build is successful, `XFormsContainingDocument.java` still displays an error when viewing the source: `'XFormsContainingDocument' must either ve declared abstract or implement abstract method `parentXBLCcontainer()' in 'XBLContainer'`. The error appears to be accurate.

Comment: Glad it's working! I suspect there is another `Try` in scope. Scala resolves relative to previous imports, and `scala` is implicitly imported. So writing `scala.util.Try` cannot hurt.

Comment: The error with `XFormsContainingDocument` is due to a bug in IntelliJ's Scala support. You will see such errors on occasion. The IntelliJ guys rewrote an entire Scala parser, and it is not yet perfect, in particular when it comes to Scala/Java integration. Ideally we should report bugs to them.

Comment: I hopefully [fixed the imports](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/e4e27c1a0105ae960e3018e41d78efa1fe51de78).

Comment: Thanks, there were actually a number of files that had these errors. I'll answer my own question and include the full list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this error by changing the import from:
`import util.Try` to `import scala.util.Try`

There were other files that had the same issue with the `scala.xml` package.

The full list of files I changed is:

```
src\main\scala\org\orbeon\oxf\common\PEVersion.scala
src\main\scala\org\orbeon\oxf\fr\mongodb\MongoDBPersistence.scala
src\main\scala\org\orbeon\oxf\fr\process\ProcessInterpreter.scala
src\main\scala\org\orbeon\oxf\fr\process\SimpleProcess.scala
src\main\scala\org\orbeon\oxf\fr\process\XFormsActions.scala
src\main\scala\org\orbeon\oxf\xforms\action\XFormsAPI.scala
src\main\scala\org\orbeon\oxf\xforms\analysis\ElementAnalysis.scala
src\main\scala\org\orbeon\oxf\xforms\analysis\PathMapXPathAnalysis.scala
src\main\scala\org\orbeon\oxf\xforms\control\controls\XFormsInputControl.scala
src\main\scala\org\orbeon\scaxon\XML.scala
src\test\scala\org\orbeon\oxf\common\VersionTest.scala
```

Comment: Thanks I [ran "Optimize Imports"](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/c9c31ba967efbe8a4a543231579ba88d0b450f40) on those files.